# Automatically save attachments in sent emails

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to save attachments in emails I send from a certain mailbox.

I want to save files that begin with certain strings, and the files need to go in different folders based on the string.

I think the code should be working in the background, but nothing gets saved.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim strSaveFolder As String
    Dim objAttachment As Attachment
    Dim strAttachmentName As String

    strSaveFolder = "C:\Users\user\Documents\savemaps\"

    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

    If Item.SenderName = "mymail@mail.com" Then
        For Each objAttachment In Item.Attachments
            strAttachmentName = objAttachment.FileName
            If InStr(1, strAttachmentName, "String1 ", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                objAttachment.SaveAsFile strSaveFolder & "map1\" & strAttachmentName
            ElseIf InStr(1, strAttachmentName, "String2 ", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                objAttachment.SaveAsFile strSaveFolder & "map2\" & strAttachmentName
            ElseIf ...
            ...
            End If
        Next objAttachment
    End If

    Set objAttachment = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm sure the destination exists.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the code to confirm it is actually being called? You have used `Private` - try using `Public` instead.
If it is being called, step through the code line by line so you can see what is happening.

Comment: Do you have the other required code in place?  You need an initialized Outlook Application object as shown here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend

Comment: When using `Application` no initialisation required. Code goes in `ThisOutlookSession`.

Comment: Have you checked whether the value returned by Item.SenderName equals the actual email address? It could also be giving you the name associated with the email address. This would explain why nothing is happening when the code runs. If so, try using Item.SenderEmailAddress instead. -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.senderemailaddress